# Unable to get value for heading tags using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<h6>` tag like following:

```
<h6 id='some-id' value='processing'> Processing </h6>
```

I am unable to get value of `<h6>` using script like following:

```
var processing_status = document.getElementById('some-id').value;
```

I can't understand what is wrong here?

Comment: Eventually I understand what was wrong in my code, which is I tried to access the value of non-input HTML element but “value()” function in js should be used with HTML input elements.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by following different way :

```
var processing_status = document.getElementById('some-id').innerHTML;

var processing_status1 = document.getElementsByTagName("H6")[0].getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 1):

**This can be done by following different way :**

```js
var processing_status = document.getElementById('some-id').innerHTML;
console.log(processing_status);
var processing_status1 = document.getElementsByTagName("H6")[0].getAttribute("value");
console.log(processing_status1);
```

```html
<h6 id='some-id' value='processing'> Processing </h6>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the value of the id only after loading the HTML. Please put it in `onload` or inside `document.ready`. Use `innerHTML` instead of value. Here is a sample script. To get the value property you can use `getAttribute` method.

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
           function LoadScript(){
               console.log(document.getElementById("some-id").innerHTML);
               console.log(document.getElementById("some-id").getAttribute("value")) 
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="LoadScript()">
        <h6 id='some-id' value='processing'> Processing </h6> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value`

```js
var processing_status = document.getElementById('some-id').innerHTML;
console.log(processing_status);
```

```html
<h6 id='some-id' value='processing'> Processing </h6>
```